# Debugging and/or Optimize an DataSnap Delphi Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi, memory-management, firedac

I have made a Delphi XE10+ Android application.
The purpose of application is to synchronize a local SQLite database with a server database (firebird) via a DataSnap Standard (not REST) server.
The Delphi Android Application is using the FireDac components.
On local SQLite database are 10 tables almost identical (as structure) with the server database (firebird).
The main goal is to get the records that are added/modified on the server and insert/update the local database.
Depending on the table is necessary to made additional task on local database. Like another insert in another table.
I have made on the DataSnap Server 10 TSQLDataset that are available from android application as Client Dataset.

I have the following problem.
The application crashes when are more than 10000 records to process in one table. (More or less depending on how many columns the table has).
project xxx raised exception class aborted (6)
project xxx raised exception class Stopped (signal) (17)

The application work no problem in win32.

Here is the main logic of the synchronize.
open client dataset from datasnap server.
loop the clientdataset
for each server record check if local record exist.
start transaction
if not exist - insert. if exist - edit.
copy field values.
post the firedac query.
commit transaction
next record on server.
done
next table
done
next table

```
function  ImportXXX(serverData : TClientDataSet; workQuery : TFDQuery; 
workConnection : TFDConnection;
workProvider : TDSProviderConnection; serverConnection : TsrvMethodsClient;
lastVersion : Integer; serverVersion : Integer) : Boolean;
begin
//            open client dataset from server
  serverData.ProviderName := 'dsCalduri';
  serverData.Params.CreateParam(ftInteger, 'ARECVERSION', ptInput);
  serverData.Params.ParamByName('ARECVERSION').AsInteger := lastVersion;
  serverData.Active := True;

// for each record do something
  while not serverData.Eof do begin
    workQuery.Close;
    workQuery.SQL.Clear;
    workQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM CALDURI WHERE IDGLOBAL = :AIDGLOBAL');
    workQuery.ParamByName('AIDGLOBAL').AsString := serverData.FieldByName('IDGLOBAL').AsString;
    workQuery.Open;
    workConnection.StartTransaction;
    if workQuery.IsEmpty then begin
      workQuery.Insert;
    end else begin
      workQuery.Edit;
    end;
    workQuery.FieldByName('IDGLOBAL').AsString      := serverData.FieldByName('IDGLOBAL').AsString;
    workQuery.FieldByName('REC_VERSION').AsInteger  := serverData.FieldByName('REC_VERSION').AsInteger;
    workQuery.Post;
    workConnection.Commit;
    Inc(indexOk);
    serverData.Next;
  end;
end;
```

All the components used by the function (client dataset, query for check/insert/edit, etc) are design time components. (using runtime components like I did in the past result into more usage of memory). As far I can observe.

Questions
1. How to determine what is eating the memory? What to debug? what to log in order to help?
2. How to change the code in order to not crash the application? Any advice?
3. is my logic and modeling of the project ok? or with android must rethink the project?
Razvan

Comment: My first guess is that you are killing your UI responsivness by executing a too long process in the main thread. The cure would be to move the time taking task to a worker thread.

Comment: Are you sure that (signal) (17) is memory related? Processing a large dataset might consume time and memory. So @TomBrunberg might be on to something with his guess.

Comment: Transaction handling looks a bit odd and might create some overhead. You do `workConnection.StartTransaction;` and `workConnection.Commit;` for each record in `serverData` (and in no case a rollback?). That means 10000 transactions if there are 10000 records on your server. Maybe what you mean is to encapsulate the whole loop in **one** transaction?

Comment: I'm not killing the UI. After I moved into a thread all the code, the result is the same (or sligthly worse). What I mean by worse if that the operating sistem is killing the thread, i get no feedback, and i'm in a worse state than before :). (when the operating sistem is killing the entire application, and I least I can see that (as a user)).

Comment: I do rollback. Is not written in the example. my bad. there is one try except end that encapsulate whole and in the except part I'm doing some stuff except the rollback. (feedback and so on). It is a good idea to move in a 100-500 records the start and commit, however this can be only an optimization. my question is why is not working now? why the operation system is killing the application? because the transaction handling?

Answer (score 0):

With TFDQuery:
Close
PramaByName(...)
Prepare
Open
If (Active) then ...

TFDQuery performs better when the Prepare proc is called.
CHECK allocation size of strings in SQLite and SERVER. (NVARCHAR?)